# how can i save event log information in a excel using powershell

Tags: powershell, csv, export-to-csv

i'm new to ps scripting , i want to export certain data from event logs. I tried following

```
$events = Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{logname="Microsoft-Windows-Storage-Storport/Health"; id=511}

# get the first event raw XML
$event = [xml]$events[0].ToXml()
$event.Event.EventData.Data | Where-Object {$_.name -eq "BootDevice"}
```

and i was getting output as:

| Name | #text |
| --- | --- |
| BootDevice | true |

but when i tried to export its value to excel it gives me error.

Here is my complete code:

```
$Myexcel = New-Object -ComObject excel.application
$Myexcel.visible = $true
$Myworkbook = $Myexcel.workbooks.add()
$Sheet1 = $Myworkbook.worksheets.item(1)
$Sheet1.name = "summary"
$Sheet1.cells.item(1,1) = 'BootDevice'
$events = Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{logname="Microsoft-Windows-Storage-Storport/Health"; id=511}

# get the first event raw XML
$event = [xml]$events[0].ToXml()

# display its content
#$event.Event.EventData.Data
$BootDevice=$event.Event.EventData.Data | Where-Object {$_.name -eq "BootDevice"}
write-output $BootDevice
$Sheet1.cells.item(2,1) = $BootDevice
$Sheet1.Columns.AutoFit()
$Myfile = 'E:\tmp\test.csv'
$Myworkbook.Saveas($Myfile)
$Myexcel.displayalerts = $true
```

But its giving error

```
Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC
At line:16 char:1
+$Sheet1.cells.item(2,1) = $BootDevice
```

And a blank excel is generated.

Any help will be thankfull.

Comment: I admire your efforts, but question why not use ImportExcel module?

Comment: I have a question. Are you able to find the Data in CSV files.

Comment: @NarayanaLvsl,thanks for reply only header is showing up, value part is still blank in csv

Comment: @f22l2, thanks for reply, i tried but same error comes up

Answer (score 0):

When manually creating an Excel file like this, you need to set the values and headers cell by cell.

Try

```
$Myexcel = New-Object -ComObject excel.application
$Myexcel.Visible = $true
$Myexcel.DisplayAlerts = $true
$Myworkbook = $Myexcel.workbooks.add()
$Sheet1 = $Myworkbook.worksheets.item(1)
$Sheet1.Name = "summary"
$Sheet1.Cells.Item(1,1) = 'BootDevice'
$Sheet1.Cells.Item(1,2) = 'Value'

$events = Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{logname="Microsoft-Windows-Storage-Storport/Health"; id=511} | Select-Object -First 1
# get the first event raw XML
$event = [xml]$events.ToXml()

# display its content
$BootDevice = $event.Event.EventData.Data | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq "BootDevice"}
write-output $BootDevice
$Sheet1.Cells.Item(2,1) = $BootDevice.Name
$Sheet1.Cells.Item(2,2) = $BootDevice.'#text'
$Sheet1.Columns.AutoFit()

# if you want to save in some other format than .XLSX, see what value you need for the second parameter of .SaveAs()
# XlFileFormat enumeration: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlfileformat
$Myfile = 'E:\tmp\Test\test.xlsx'
$Myworkbook.SaveAs($Myfile)

# quit Excel and clear the used COM objects from memory
$Myexcel.Quit()

$null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($Sheet1)
$null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($Myworkbook)
$null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($Myexcel)
[System.GC]::Collect()
[System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
```

By using `Select-Object -First 1` you effectively stop the gathering of events when you have found one, saving a lot of unnecessary time to first read all matching events and then only use the first one as in your code.

The above should give you an Excel file looking like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Below code fetches the log events that you are looking for and exported to CSV file(test.csv)

```
 $events = Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{logname="Microsoft-Windows-Storage-Storport/Health"; id=511}
    
    $events | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation test.csv
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: Added comments @MarkRotteveel